# Replacing a native Object (Array) method with a custom method: Is it safe? Compatible?

Tags: javascript

I've got an array, and it's got a method I threw onto it called `add`, which I use as a wrapper around `push`. I've found myself using `push` a few times when I should have used `add`, and now I'm thinking it would be nice to assign a reference to my `add` method to the array's native `push`. Thus, calling `push` on the array would call `add`.

Do internals depend on externally available native methods like `push`? How would this affect compatibility? Is this a bad idea? If so, why?

*Some code*:

```
PR.state = {
   views: []
};

_.extend(PR.state.views, {

   add: function(view) {
     var parent = view.parent;
     if ((!this.length && view instanceof PR.Views.App) || (parent && _.contains(this, parent)))
       this.push(view);
   }

});

// I am thinking:
PR.state.views.push = PR.state.views.add;
```

Comment: Posting some code would help us understand the question/problem better :-)

Comment: It does seem like a bad idea, I would just take the time and search/replace where needed.

Comment: My uninformed guess would be that *all* major third party libraries (jQuery, etc.) rely on `Array.prototype.push`. You don't want to redefine it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I wouldn't overwrite `Array.prototype.push`. Just that particular instance's.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Blender: actually it changes thing in a bad way: changing behaviour of a single object is even worse, than changing behaviour of a prototype

Comment: @zerkms: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Blender: your wrapper answer was interesting. Only problem was that I would lost functionality like `PR.state.views.length`. I'd have to wrap-through all the array methods I wanted to use.

Comment: If you are just changing it on your objects, fine. The downside is that you need to add the method to every instance (since you say you aren't going to modify `Array.prototype`). But it doesn't seem like a good solution, why not just fix the code and use `push` where you need `push` and `add` where you need `add`?

Comment: @RobG: For what it's worth, this is a "singleton". And yeah, I am just wondering. I fixed the code before posting this question :D

Comment: Because, it's a micro-optimization on a small part of your app which you've already mentioned you can't keep one or the other straight. This is where "side effects" and "unintended consequences" get birthed. Wrap it first-class and get on with it, but don't impersonate it through short-sightedness to paper over what's really a coding discipline problem (no offense, by the way).

Comment: @Blender: it's reversed duck typing :-) If you see a duck, you expect it to walk and quack like a duck.

Comment: So the generic philosophy is not to override/alter the default implementation of any native object, even if it is for a specific instance. The wrapper you've written is a good approach. However, if you end up using the Array push more often - then you need to fix that. Adding a reference to add

Comment: Thanks @PradeepBanavara. Yeah, it seems like a stupid thing to do. I I appreciate your focus on my thinking it may not be utterly terrible for just one instance. But, what do you mean by "then you need to fix that. Adding a reference to add"? Fix what—the using of `Array.prototype.push` more often than my own wrapper, `add`? And adding a reference `add` where?

Comment: @dimadima Sorry what I meant was this - if you put a reference to the add wrapper in the push method, they you'd have to test for all the code where push is used, to make sure that it's not broken. Seems like a humungous effort. Instead what you might want to do is fix the code that is using push instead of add. That effort will be considerably less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise against changing the behavior of a standard array method.  If you really want a custom method, then just create a new method and give it it's own unique name and use that.

Changing the behavior of existing methods could have all sorts of bad consequences:

1. Incompatibility with code retrieved from any other source.
2. Creates a non-standard and unexpected implementation if anybody else ever works on this project.  This is like adding in a time bomb to trip up some future developer.
3. Training yourself to use your own custom method instead of `.push()` is just something that a decent developer would do.  Just do it.
4. Creating a newly named method with an appropriate and descriptive name improves the readability, understandability and maintainability of your code.  Replacing an existing method with something that works differently does the opposite.

It's not so bad if you just replace the method on one instance of an array, not the whole array prototype, but it's still not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Still hoping there might be other more concrete bullets here, even though of course all of the above seems just about right.

Comment: @dimadima - Time for some [fuzzy principle](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: for the record, I am approaching this completely unprincipled. I am definitely not doing what I asked about.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - great article.  The keys in [that article](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/) are that it's an "unnecessary" method that carries "unforeseen" risks with no advantage to make it worth take on those unforeseen risks.

Comment: That guy's proto-geek nerd freak on PHP for not being Python is 100% gold.

Comment: @dimadima - well you could make `.oldPush()` be the original `.push()` before you replace push, but still you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @jfriend00: `push.noConflict()` :D

Answer (score 0):

What a stupid question. If I replace `push` with `add`, then what happens when I call `push` from `add`? :< :< I haven't tested it, but I suspect that while `Array.prototype.push` will still be available, unless I use `Array.prototype.push` explicitly, calling `add` will result in a mondo endless loop.